# Using loop inside defmacro

Tags: loops, lisp, common-lisp, lisp-macros

I'm learning (common) Lisp, and as exercise, I want to implement 'xond', a `cond` macro, that transform this silly example:

```
(xond (= n 1) (setq x 2) (= n 2) (setq x 1))
```

into a if-else chain:

```
(if (= n 1) (setq x 2) (if (= n 2) (setq x 1)))
```

Currently, I have this macro:

```
(defmacro xond (&rest x) (if x (list 'progn (list 'if (pop x) (pop x)))))
```

that just expand the first two items in `x`:

```
(macroexpand '(xond (= x 1) (setq y 2)))
```

produce

```
(PROGN (IF (= X 1) (SETQ Y 2))) ;
```

Now I want to process all items in `x`, so I add a `loop` to produce a if-serie (a step toward if-else-version):

```
(defmacro xond (&rest x)
  (loop (if x
           (list 'progn (list 'if (pop x) (pop x)))
           (return t))))
```

but then macro seems to stop working:

```
(macroexpand '(xond (= x 1) (setq y 2)))
T ;
```

What I'm missing here?

**Edition**

verdammelt's answer put me in the right track, and coredump's made me change my approach to an iterative one.

Now I'll implement `(xond test1 exp1 test2 exp2)` as:

```
(block nil
   test1 (return exp1)
   test2 (return exp2)
)
```

which can be done by iteration.

I'm writing this for my minimal Lisp interpreter; I have only implemented the most basic functions.

This is what I wrote. I'm using `la` to accumulate the parts of the output.

```
(defmacro xond (&rest x) 
   (let ((la '())) 
      (loop 
         (if x (push (list 'if (pop x) (list 'return (pop x))) la) 
               (progn (push 'nil la)
                      (push 'block la)
                      (return la)
                )))))
```

with

```
(macroexpand '(xond (= x 1) (setq y 2) (= X 2) (setq y 1)))
```

result:

```
(BLOCK NIL 
    (IF (= X 2) (RETURN (SETQ Y 1)))
    (IF (= X 1) (RETURN (SETQ Y 2)))
) ;
```

**Second edition**

Add a label to `block` and change `return` to `return-from`, to avoid conflict with other `return` inside arguments. Also changed `push` for `append` to generate code in the same orden as the parameters.

```
(defmacro xond (&rest x) 
    (let ((label (gensym)) (la '()) (condition nil) (expresion nil)) 
        (setq la (append la (list 'block label)))
        (loop 
            (if x   
                (setq la (append la (list 
                   (list 'if (pop x) (list 'return-from label (pop x))))))
                 (return la)))))
```

So

```
(macroexpand '(xond (= x 1) (setq y 2) (= X 2) (setq y 1)))
```

now gives

```
(BLOCK #:G3187 (IF (= X 1) (RETURN-FROM #:G3187 (SETQ Y 2))) (IF (= X 2) (RETURN-FROM #:G3187 (SETQ Y 1))))
```

Comment: The edit introduces a different expansion which has a different semantics, ie. If multiple tests are true. Maybe you want to add a return clause?

Comment: @coredump. I edited my question to add a return as suggested.

Comment: Your `(block nil ... (return ...))` approach is not hygienic: consider `(loop ... (xond ... (return 3)) ...)`.  You definitely don't need to use `return` / `return-from` in a macro like this, but if you do, do it hygienically by using a gensym for the block name.

Comment: @tfb. Just edited my question with your comments. I want to use 'return' to skip remaining conditions.

Comment: You don't need to do that if you take the obvious approach (as recommended in coredump's answer) of generating `(if c1 r1 (if c2 r2 ...))`.  That's hugely more natural in an expression language like Lisp than some sucky imperative thing with explicit control transfers all over the place.

Comment: @tfb. I understand that, but it needs several not-yet-implemented functions in my minimal Lisp interpreter.

Comment: @CandidMoe: it needs working macroexpansion, that's all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some remarks

- You do not need a `progn` when you only expand into a single `if`
- The use of `pop` might be confusing for the reader (and the programmer too) since it mutates a place, maybe you want to start with a less imperative approach

Also, in that case I don't think a `loop` approach is helpful, because you need to nest the expressions that come *after* in the body *inside* a previously built form, and even though it can be done, it is a bit more complex to do that simply a recursive function or a "recursive" macro.

Here I explain both approach, starting with "recursive" macro (the quote here is because the macro does not call itself, but expands as call to itself).

#### Macro expansion fixpoint

If I had to implement `xond`, I would write a macro that expands into other calls to `xond`, until macroexpansion reaches a base case where there are no more `xond`:

```
(defmacro xond (&rest body)
  (if (rest body)
      (destructuring-bind (test if-action . rest) body
        `(if ,test ,if-action (xond ,@rest)))
      (first body)))
```

For example, this expression:

```
(xond (= n 1) (setq x 2) (= n 2) (setq x 1))
```

First macroexpands into:

```
(if (= n 1)
    (setq x 2)
    (xond (= n 2) (setq x 1)))
```

And eventually reaches a fixpoint with:

```
(if (= n 1)
    (setq x 2)
    (if (= n 2)
        (setq x 1)
        nil))
```

Be careful, you cannot directly use `xond` inside the definition of `xond`, what happens is that the macro *expands* as a call to `xond`, which Lisp then expands again. If you are not careful, you may end up with an infinite macroexpansion, that's why you need a base case where the macro does *not* expand into `xond`.

#### Macro calling a recursive function

Alternatively, you can call a recursive function inside your macro, and expand all the inner forms at once.

With [`LABELS`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_flet_.htm), you bind `xond-expand` to a recursive function. Here this is an actual recursive approach:

```
(labels ((xond-expand (body)
           (if body
               (list 'if
                     (pop body)
                     (pop body)
                     (xond-expand body))
               nil)))
  (xond-expand '((= n 1) (setq x 2) (= n 2) (setq x 1))))

 ; => (IF (= N 1)
 ;    (SETQ X 2)
 ;    (IF (= N 2)
 ;        (SETQ X 1)
 ;        NIL))
```

Comment: Depending on what `xond` is meant to do there might need to be an error case for an arglist length of 1 I think (it should be zero or 2 or more).

Comment: @tfb in the macro destructuring-bind would error but I agree there should be better error handling. In the labels I will rewrite to use pop too, so that it will error too.

Comment: @tfb I don't expect error handling in the answer. That can be added later.

Answer (score 2):

Your `xond` macro ends with `(return t)` so it evaluates to `t` rather than your accumulated `if` expressions.

You could use `loop`'s `collect` clause to accumulate the code you wish to return. For example: `(loop for x in '(1 2 3) collect (* 2 x))` would evaluate to `(2 4 6)`.

Comment: I see that now. I understand the problem; in Python I would accumulate strings in a list and return a `join` an the end, but here, I'm lost. Code will be appreciated.

Comment: If I get time to spend on this problem I will see if I can produce something to help you. For now I've added a suggestion about the `collect` clause of `loop` which would probably be useful here.

Comment: You answer give the hint to solve the problem. I'm learning Lisp and want to solve it with the most basic tools.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
(ql:quickload :alexandria)

(defun as-last (l1 l2)
  `(,@l1 ,l2))

(defmacro xond (&rest args)
  (reduce #'as-last
          (loop for (condition . branch) in (alexandria:plist-alist args)
                collect `(if ,condition ,branch))
          :from-end t))

(macroexpand-1 '(xond c1 b1 c2 b2 c3 b3))
;; (IF C1 B1 (IF C2 B2 (IF C3 B3))) ;
;; T
```

`alexandria`'s `plist-alist` was used to pair the arguments,
the intrinsic destructuring in `loop` used to extract conditions and branches.

The helper function `as-last` stacks lists together in the kind of
`(a b c) (d e f) => (a b c (d e f))`.

`(reduce ... :from-end t)` right-folds the sequence of the collected `(if condition branch)` clauses stacking them into each other using `#'as-last`.

#### Without any dependencies

('though, does `alexandria` even count as a dependency? ;) )

```
(defun pairs (l &key (acc '()) (fill-with-nil-p nil))
  (cond ((null l) (nreverse acc))
        ((null (cdr l)) (pairs (cdr l) 
                               :acc (cons (if fill-with-nil-p
                                              (list (car l) nil)
                                              l) 
                                          acc) 
                               :fill-with-nil-p fill-with-nil-p))
        (t (pairs (cdr (cdr l)) 
                  :acc (cons (list (car l) (cadr l)) acc) 
                  :fill-with-nil-p fill-with-nil-p))))

(defun as-last (l1 l2)
  `(,@l1 ,l2))

(defmacro xond (&rest args)
  (reduce #'as-last
          (loop for (condition branch) in (pairs args)
                         collect `(if ,condition ,branch))
          :from-end t))

(macroexpand-1 '(xond c1 b1 c2 b2 c3 b3))
;; (IF C1 B1 (IF C2 B2 (IF C3 B3))) ;
;; T
```

The helper function `pairs` makes out of `(a b c d e f)` => `((a b) (c d) (e f))`.

(`:fill-with-nil-p` determines in case of odd number of list elements, whether the last element would be listed `(last-el)` or `(last-el nil)` - in the latter case filled with `nil`).